# Realtime authentication in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

So i am currently learning nodejs and am having a few problems with the workflow in node. I want to build a register system for starters and when a user is typing his username, i want to check the input on the server side if the username already exists in the database.

I'm thinking something like this would do the trick, but I am not sure if its a good way to do real-time authentication.

On index page we have an input with the name and id of "username" and:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
   $('#username').on('keyup', function(e){ 
var parameter = { parameter: $(this).val() };
   $.get( '/validate',parameter, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
 }); 
 });
</script>
```

So my idea is to use the onkeyup function and then use the $.get function to send the request.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

router.get('/validate', function(req, res) {
     var val=req.query.parameter;
    if (val!=undefined){
        var query=req.connection.query("select * from registeredusers where username="+req.connection.escape(val),function(err,result){
            if(err){
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log(query.sql);
            var num=result.length;
            console.log(num);
            if(num==1){

                res.send('Username already exists ');                       
            }

         });
    }
});
```

In the past I worked a lot with php and so I used ajax, but now im not sure if i should still use ajax, so my questions are:
Is this the correct way to do real-time authentication or is there a better way? 
Can you point me to the correct direction by sharing with me some code of how things should look like in the register system?

Comment: I don't see why you cannot use your endpoint to validate with ajax? Client side you should be able to exactly what you were doing before. Server side if in PHP you need an endpoint that accepts requests and validates a user you should be able to do exactly the same in node.js as well. The implementation changes but the idea is the same. Code wise the only big issue that I see is that you do `console.log(query.sql);` inside your callback and the assignment of the query `var query=...` it is also very weird.

Comment: Well I knew that i could validate with ajax, i just wasnt sure that it was the best way to do things since im new to nodejs. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Again concepts in web development apply everywhere the same. Implementation differs. Extra tip, your javascript needs a bit more work :), but you are in a good way.

Comment: thank you, i think i know how things work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X_maras has actually everything already sad. If you like use your ajax to send the requests. But i would suggest you to get a program like postman to test your api and make the request from there. Here a little snipped. i have keep the wording as "parameter" but would recommend you to use id or userId or etc

```
router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    var val = req.body.parameter // if you send the parameter in body
    var val = req.params.parameter // if you send it as a url parameter
    if (val !== undefined){
        return res.send("no parameter provided")
    }
    var user = ... // do here your database stuff
    if(err){  
        console.error(err)
        return res.send("Error")
    }
    if(!user){
        // register the user
    }

    res.send({user: user})
})
```

Comment: Is there a better way than ajax to send requests? or is there a somewhat lighter approach on sending requests to server every time a user types into an input field?

Comment: If you are familiär with Ajax and you are trying to Build a Web App in the Browser i See no Problem with Ajax. But you could also use jquery or plain

Comment: can you tell me what do you mean by "plain"?

Comment: Ah i understand you problem you don't want to restart the socket. Hm but i really don't know if this is possible if you find it out plz added here i will also start a bit looking for it. Ah and sorry i should be "plain js" so just javascript without any kind of framework.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and yes, i dont want to restart the socket, but i am searching for solutions and will update the post when I will found one.